How to specify color with geom_line, geom_point, and annotate in ggplot2?
I'm trying to modify Jeff Lewis (2023-10-23) Polarization in Congress, and I cannot control the color in geom_line and geom_point.
The following seems to be the closest I've come to what I want with a subset of 12 of his
2774 points:
library(ggplot2)
PolarDatSmpl <- data.frame(
  year=rep(c(1879, 1951, 2023), 4), 
  chamber=rep(c('House', 'Senate'), e=3, len=12), 
  party=rep(c('DEM', 'REP'), e=6), 
  value=c(-.39, -.26, -.38, -.45, -.20, -.35, 
           .40,  .28,  .51,  .30,  .28,  .55) )

PolarDatSmpl$pc <- with(PolarDatSmpl, 
    interaction(party, chamber))
  
# I want lines and points labeled with colors 
# and text 

PolarColors <- data.frame(
  chamber=rep(c('House', 'Senate'), e=2), 
  party=rep(c('DEM', 'REP'), 2), 
  Color=c('blue', 'red', 'darkblue', 'darkred'), 
  yearTxt=c(1960.3, 1944.3, 1961, 1945),  
  yearPch=c(1944.3, 1927.8, 1944, 1928), 
  value=c(-.4, .5, -.33, .4) )

#value=c(-.5, .4, -.43, .35) )
#c(.5, .4, -.43, -.35) 
PolarColors$pc <- with(PolarColors, 
    interaction(party, chamber))
rownames(PolorColors) <- PolarColors$pc

PolarDatSmpl$Color <- PolarColors[
  PolarDatSmpl$pc, 'Color']

p1 <- ggplot(data=PolarDatSmpl, 
    aes(x=year, y=value, group=pc, color=Color)) +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position='none') + 
  geom_line() + geom_point(mapping=aes(
    shape=factor(chamber) )) 

# What do I need to do to get the desired colors? 

p2 <- p1 + with(PolarColors, annotate('text', 
    x=yearTxt, y=value, label=pc, color=Color)) + 
  geom_point(PolarColors, mapping = aes( 
    x=yearPch, y=value, shape=factor(chamber) ))
p2

This gives me everything I want EXCEPT for the color of points and lines. I can specify the color with annotate and a companion cal to geom_plot to put a legend where I want it, but I have failed to control the line color. (I once got the points and lines colored, but that broke when I added annotate.)
Suggestions? Thanks, Spencer Graves

To use R colour names/hex values from a df column, use scale_color_identity(). Note that the default behaviour for scale_color_identity() is to not create a legend, but you still need theme(legend.position = "none") to suppress the shape aesthetic legend.
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = PolarDatSmpl,
       aes(year, value, group = pc, colour = Color)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(chamber))) +
  geom_point(data = PolarColors, 
             aes(yearPch, value, group = pc, color = Color, shape = factor(chamber))) +
  with(PolarColors,
       annotate('text', yearTxt, value, label = pc, color = Color)) + 
  scale_color_identity() +
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(legend.position = "none")


Based on your comment, using geom_text():
ggplot(data = PolarDatSmpl,
       aes(year, value, group = pc, colour = Color)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(chamber))) +
  geom_point(data = PolarColors, 
             aes(yearPch, value, group = pc, color = Color, shape = factor(chamber))) +
  geom_text(data = PolarColors,
            aes(yearPch, value, label = pc, color = Color),
            hjust = 0,
            nudge_x = 2) + 
  scale_color_identity() +
  theme_bw() +  
  theme(legend.position = "none")


Thanks very much. I have admired ggplot2 since it was introduced, but the learning curve has been intimidating. I spent over a day on this, starting with code from Jeff Lewis that almost worked, and over half that time was this one issue! Most of that time was reading documentation and other discussions of similar questions ... without seeing "scale_color_identity()"! Thanks again, Spencer Graves

Using geom_point()+geom_text() instead of annotate()

@SpencerGraves - updated answer accordingly. Note you can omit x = and y = as the first two aes() values are interpreted as x and y by default.

Using geom_point()+geom_text() instead of annotate()
It's easier to specify the joint position of symbol and text using
geom_point()+geom_text() instead of annotate(). This can be done as follows:
PolarDatSmpl <- data.frame(
  year=rep(c(1879, 1951, 2023), 4), 
  chamber=rep(c('House', 'Senate'), e=3, len=12), 
  party=rep(c('DEM', 'REP'), e=6), 
  value=c(-.39, -.26, -.38, -.45, -.20, -.35, 
           .40,  .28,  .51,  .30,  .28,  .55) )

PolarDatSmpl$pc <- with(PolarDatSmpl, 
    interaction(party, chamber))
  
# I want lines and points labeled with colors 
# and text 

PolarColors <- data.frame(
  chamber=rep(c('House', 'Senate'), e=2), 
  party=rep(c('DEM', 'REP'), 2), 
  Color=c('blue', 'red', 'darkblue', 'darkred'), 
  yearTxt=c(1960.3, 1944.3, 1961, 1945),  
  yearPch=c(1944.3, 1927.8, 1944, 1928), 
  value=c(-.4, .5, -.33, .4) )

PolarColors$pc <- with(PolarColors, 
    interaction(party, chamber))
rownames(PolarColors) <- 
  as.character(PolarColors$pc)

PolarDatSmpl$Color <- PolarColors[
  PolarDatSmpl$pc, 'Color']

P1 <- ggplot(data = PolarDatSmpl,
       aes(x = year, y = value, group = pc, color = Color)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(chamber))) +
  geom_point(PolarColors, mapping = aes(x = yearPch, 
      y = value, shape = factor(chamber))) +
  scale_color_identity() +
  theme_bw() +  theme(legend.position = "none")

P2 <- P1 + geom_point(PolarColors, mapping=
        aes(x=yearPch, y=value, group=pc, 
            color=Color, shape = factor(chamber))) 

P2 + geom_text(PolarColors, mapping=aes(
          x=yearPch, y=value, group=pc, color=Color), 
       label=PolarColors$pc, hjust = 0, nudge_x = 2)

It took me a while to figure this out.
I provide it here in case it might help someone else.
